# Add alt attribute to a leaflet marker

Tags: javascript

I have a structure of a leaflet showing the current marker

---

```
  $marker = array(
    'type' => 'point',
    'lat' => $lat,
    'lon' => $lon,
  );

  // Add icon only if we got url (most of the times).
  if ($marker_url) {
    $marker['icon'] = array(
      'iconUrl' => $marker_url,
      'iconSize' => array('x' => '38', 'y' => '38'),
    );
  }
  $markers[] = $marker;
```

---

How can i add, via code, an alt attribute to a leaflet marker in drupal?

Thx!